# Django - how to make temporary (on disk) file from uploaded (memory) file?

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I'm working on a project where user uploads a file during creating the order. The file is sent through AJAX to a `view` and then recognized number of words which returns back.

For this purpose, I want to use `textract` module. The problem is that I haven't found a way how to add an inmemory uploaded file as an `textract.process(filepath)` argument since it wants `filepath`, not a `file`.

So I suppose I should save this file temporary on the drive and send a path to this file to `process` function.

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_file_word_count(request):
    from SolutionsForLanguages import word_counter
    file = request.FILES.get('file')
    count = word_counter.count_words(file)
    return JsonResponse({'word_count': count})
```

How can I do that so the file is immediately deleted after words are counted?

Answer (score 0):

Look at pythons tempfile module. You can use it to create a temporary file and using that file objects path property, get the file path then pass it to your intended function. I guess it should work and then you can delete the temp file.